# Remove empty array from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object arrays, and one of the dates is empty, I would like to remove that empty date.

```
const arr = [
  {
    "2022-03-10": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Consulta General", "read": false }
    ],
    "2022-03-26": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Follow Up", "read": false }
    ],
    "2022-03-27": [],
    "2022-03-31": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Valoraciones Funcionales", "read": false }
    ]
  }
];
```

What I've tried

```
list.push(doc.data());
var filtered = list.filter(function (el) {
  return el != " ";
});
```

I would like to keep the same array, just without the "2022-03-27" item.

Also, if it is also possible to filter directly from the doc.data() without having to do the list.push, that would be much better.

Comment: It looks like you actually want to filter the properties of the object, not filter the array.

Comment: @Barmar if possible yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over the array
- Using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), get the list of entries for the current object
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), filter the entries whose value is an empty array
- Using [`Object#fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), return the current object containing the filtered entries

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "2022-03-10": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Consulta General", "read": false }
    ],
    "2022-03-26": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Follow Up", "read": false }
    ],
    "2022-03-27": [],
    "2022-03-31": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Valoraciones Funcionales", "read": false }
    ]
  }
];

const filtered = arr.map(obj => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => value.length > 0)
  )
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I was preparing a similar answer, but in mine I filtered `doc.data()` before doing `list.push()`, so we don't need to map over the entire array every time we add an object to it.

Comment: @Barmar if its not necessary to do the push, how could i do with the doc.data()?

Comment: @Majed I ended up using this solution and modifying the code to use with the doc.data().  Thanks for saving me so much time

Comment: @CarlosCraig I never said not to do the push, I said to remove the property from the object before pushing it, instead of looping over the array and removing the property then.

Comment: @Barmar it actually ended up working better without the push, so you still assisted in allowing me to think that way

Comment: @CarlosCraig You don't have multiple objects that need to be in an array? Then of course there's no need to push.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to review data structure. I restructured your code to conventional format I hope that what you mean to do. if not leave me a comment and I will recode it for you

```js
const result = [
     { 
      "2022-03-10": [],
        "Age": "31",
        "Last": "Craig",
        "Name": "Carlos",
        "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm",
        "Type": "Consulta General",
        "read": false,
      },
        {
        "2022-03-26": [],
        "Age": "31",
        "Last": "Craig",
        "Name": "Carlos",
        "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm",
        "Type": "Follow Up",
        "read": false,
      },

      { "2022-03-27": [] },
      
      {
        "2022-03-31": [],
        "Age": "31",
        "Last": "Craig",
        "Name": "Carlos",
        "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm",
        "Type": "Valoraciones Funcionales",
        "read": false,
      },
    ];
  
    const removeEmpty = result.filter(oneObj => Object.values(oneObj).length > 1);
  
    console.log(removeEmpty)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delete` to remove the parts of the object that have an empty array. This changes the original array.

```js
const arr = [{
    "2022-03-10": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Consulta General", "read": false }
    ],
    "2022-03-26": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Follow Up", "read": false }
    ],
    "2022-03-27": [],
    "2022-03-31": [
      { "Age": "31", "Last": "Craig", "Name": "Carlos", "Time": "11:00am - 12:00pm", "Type": "Valoraciones Funcionales", "read": false }
    ]
}];

arr.forEach(e =>
    Object.entries(e).forEach(([key,value]) => value.length || delete e[key])
);

console.log( arr );
```

Answer (score 0):

the main array contains one object
you can try the following solution

```
 var filtered = Object.keys(list[0]).filter(function (el) {
                  return  list[0][el].length >0
                });
```